# Problem running Transmission/Deluge

Tags: permissions, bittorrent, transmission, deluge

I have been using Firefox, Transmission/Deluge(mostly Deluge) on my Raspberry Pi now for a few weeks. I am facing this issue: Every time I click on a magnet link on the web, Firefox brings up Transmission and I am able to add the torrent but the download **does not start at all**. I have realized that downloads work only if I bring up Deluge/Transmission with sudo which brings up a fresh application with nothing enqueued.

What I want to achieve is, bring up that version of Transmission that downloads without having to use

```
gksudo transmission-gtk
```

and type my root password every time it want to add a torrent.

Thank in advance. Standing by for any further clarification you may need.

Permissions of `~/.config/transmission`:

```
$ stat -c '%U %G %A %N' ~/.config/transmission/
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxr-xr-x ‘/home/s13rw81/.config/transmission/’
```

Permissions of `~/.config/transmission/*`:

```
$ stat -c '%U %G %A %N' ~/.config/transmission/*
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxrwxr-x ‘/home/s13rw81/.config/transmission/blocklists’
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxrwxr-x ‘/home/s13rw81/.config/transmission/resume’
s13rw81 s13rw81 -rw------- ‘/home/s13rw81/.config/transmission/settings.json’
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxrwxr-x ‘/home/s13rw81/.config/transmission/torrents’
```

Comment: how is this related to ubuntu?

Comment: because its got to do with permissions and Terminal commands and giving root access to Transmission/Deluge tell me a better place to seek a solution

Comment: [unix and linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks @kos i am looking at the thread you mentioned its loaded i will let you know if it solves my porblem

Comment: @kos i dont think that thread has a solution for me. I am running Firefox and UbuntuMATE on a RaspberryPI

Comment: is it possible to run Transmission with root privileges by default ?

Comment: Sorry Whistler81, I totally missunderstood the question at first. Weird issue, I have no idea. +1

Comment: haha thanks anyway for your time. i think waht will solve my problem is if i am able to give Transmission root privileges like for ever. If i start Transmission it should start without having me type the root password everytime

Comment: If you want to notify a user of a comment use @ followed by the uername (remove the spaces from the username if any), otherwise when more than one user (beside the poster) are commenting under the post they won't receive a notification. It can be done, but really it shouldn't be needed and you should avoid running anything as root (unless it's mandatory), as it's a possible security flaw. If the client has a bug that can be exploited the risk is giving root access to the exploit. Reading again it might be a permissions problem. What are the permissions of `~/.config/transmission`?

Comment: bash: ./config/transmission: No such file or directory

Comment: You typed in the wrong path; run this :`stat -c '%U %G %A' ~/.config/transmission`, also do the same for the folder where you're downloading the torrents

Comment: s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxr-xr-x same for both

Comment: @kos the permissionswere the same for both s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxr-xr-x same for both

Comment: I suppose `s13rw81` is your user, correct? Quickly check also if the folders / files inside `~/.config/transmission` are owned by the same user: `stat -c '%U %G %A' ~/.config/transmission/*`. If yes then I'll have to pass on this.

Comment: @kos s13rw81@MyRaspberryPi:~$ stat -c '%U %G %A' ~/.config/transmission/*
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxrwxr-x
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxrwxr-x
s13rw81 s13rw81 -rw-------
s13rw81 s13rw81 drwxrwxr-x

Comment: My bad, wrong command. Please do this: `stat -c '%U %G %A %N' ~/.config/transmission/` and `stat -c '%U %G %A %N' ~/.config/transmission/*` but don't post the output in the comments, [edit] it into the question so that everyone can see it. Make sure each line of the output is indented with four spaces inside the editor; to quickly indent the output automatically paste it into the editor, select it and click on the **{ }** button at the top of the editor